# Python pandas groupby percentage to total by category

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have following table:

```
+-----+----------+---+
| Grp | Category | X |
+-----+----------+---+
|   1 | A        | 1 |
|   1 | B        | 3 |
|   1 | B        | 2 |
|   1 | C        | 2 |
|   2 | A        | 2 |
|   2 | A        | 4 |
|   2 | B        | 4 |
|   3 | A        | 3 |
|   3 | C        | 7 |
+-----+----------+---+
```

And trying to get following:

```
+-----+----------+---------+
| Grp | Category | X_ratio |
+-----+----------+---------+
|   1 | A        | 1/8     |
|   1 | B        | 5/8     |
|   1 | C        | 2/8     |
|   2 | A        | 6/10    |
|   2 | B        | 4/10    |
|   3 | A        | 3/10    |
|   3 | C        | 7/10    |
+-----+----------+---------+
```

And a little bit stuck.
Coud anyone suggest efficient solution?

My current code - its working, but seems not efficient:

```
grp_Cat = df.groupby(['Grp', 'Category ']).agg({'X': 'sum'})
grp_total = df.groupby(['Grp']).agg({'X': 'sum'})
grp_Cat.div(grp_total, level='Grp') * 100
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Updated with my current code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because performance is important first aggregate `sum` to `MultiIndex Series` and then divide by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) summed values per first `Grp` level:

```
s = df.groupby(['Grp','Category'])['X'].sum()
df = s.div(s.sum(level=0), level=0).reset_index(name='X_ratio')
print (df)
   Grp Category  X_ratio
0    1        A    0.125
1    1        B    0.625
2    1        C    0.250
3    2        A    0.600
4    2        B    0.400
5    3        A    0.300
6    3        C    0.700
```

Slowier alternative:

```
df = (df.groupby(['Grp','Category'])['X'].sum()
        .groupby(level=0)
        .apply(lambda x: x / x.sum())
        .reset_index(name='X_ratio'))
print (df)
   Grp Category  X_ratio
0    1        A    0.125
1    1        B    0.625
2    1        C    0.250
3    2        A    0.600
4    2        B    0.400
5    3        A    0.300
6    3        C    0.700
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.crosstab(index=df1.Grp,columns=df1.Category,values=df1.X,aggfunc='sum',normalize="index").stack().rename("X_ratio").reset_index()

  Grp Category  X_ratio
0    1        A    0.125
1    1        B    0.625
2    1        C    0.250
3    2        A    0.600
4    2        B    0.400
5    2        C    0.000
6    3        A    0.300
7    3        B    0.000
8    3        C    0.700
```